# "Unexpected key "foo" found in previous state received by the reducer" with redux-toolkit configure store and a custom store enhancer

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have been trying to create a store enhancer that adds some new values to my root state. However after wrapping my head around all the workings of custom enhancer I am getting an unexpected key error. I can see the new part of state in devtools and the application seems to work fine, however I am getting

```
Unexpected key "foo" found in previous state received by the reducer. 
Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: [...]. Unexpected keys will be ignored.
```

Which I simply do not understand. I tried searching around, but none of the posts I found were with the case of a custom store enhancer.

Here is the minimum code that reproduces said error. I am creating my store like this:

```typescript
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: mainReducer,
    enhancers: [testEnhancer],
});
```

Where mainReducer is just combineReducers({ "my slices" }) and all the slices are created with createSlice from RTK.

The testEnhancer looks like this:

```typescript
type StateExt = { foo: string }
export const testEnhancer: StoreEnhancer<{}, StateExt> = (next: StoreEnhancerStoreCreator): StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<{}, StateExt> => {
    
    return <S, A extends Action = AnyAction>(reducer: Reducer<S, A>, preloadedState?: PreloadedState<S>): Store<S & StateExt, A> => {
        
        const wrappedReducer: Reducer<S & StateExt, A> = (state, action) => {
            return { ...reducer(state, action), foo: 'bar' };
        };
        
        return next(wrappedReducer, { ...preloadedState, foo: '' });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually behavior that is specific to `combineReducers`.  It expects a permanent 1:1 mapping between any top-level state keys and associated slice reducers.

You'll need to have a custom reducer set up somehow that handles this, or *not* use `combineReducers` at all.  (There are many similar versions out there that do the same overall behavior but minus the warnings as well.)